# How can a non-root (Qt5/Qt6) wayland GUI also show all root files and paths in a file chooser?

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, qt6, wayland, qtwayland

I am going to port an X11 GUI (running as root) using in Qt5 via `PyQt5` and Python3 to a native wayland GUI
and Wayland does not support GUI apps running as root for security reasons.

Since it is a backup app the user must be able to select even non-user paths and files (e.g. owned by root) to be contained in the backup/restore (after privilege escalation and asking for the root password).

How can I allow a non-root wayland GUI to show all files in a file system (even those that are only visible to root)?

Note: Technically I want to use the usual [`QFileDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) of Qt5...

PS: A migration to Qt6 is on its way so a Qt6 solution is preferred

**Edit:** In Android there is a `storage.access.framework` for that and I am looking for something similar on Linux